# Creating self signed certificate using opensll xampp but getting error

Tags: openssl, xampp, self-signed

I have created a self signed certificate before, following the steps provided by this link: http://latunyj.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/generating-self-signed-certificate-in-xampp-win32-for-apache-web-server/

However, today when I installed xampp and tried to create it, I am getting the following error:
6768:error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:169:fopen< ' c:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf' , ' rb'> .............

I do not understand, can anyone tell me why I am getting such error?

Answer (score 1):

> c:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf

Chances are it can't find the openssl.cnf file. You should specify it's path on all the relevant commands with `-config`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I am creating the private key, I type: C:\xampp\apache\bin>openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024. How would I use -config? It worked last time I did it which is weird. I don't understand. Sorry I am a newb at this.

Comment: @fondillusions, add to the end of the line `-config C:\path\to\openssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, the location of the openssl config file must be set with the -config flag.

But I encountered this error in 2023. I think openssl newer versions no longer support the use of `-config`.

You can therefore set the openssl config file location as follows:

`set OPENSSL_CONF=c:/libs/openssl-0.9.8k/openssl.cnf`